# Unable to fetch data from newsapi.org using library. Help to debug

Tags: android, debugging

I m using a library to easy fetch some news from newsapi.org

```
implementation 'com.github.KwabenBerko:News-API-Java:1.0.0'
```

The library worked once, actually i loaded the news for first time... and never again since then. It not internet problem as my app works online and everything else works fine. So my problem is how can i  find what its wrong? In logcat i got message for recycleview adapter cause its empty (no data to dispaly) so this message isnt helping.
 The code i m using:

```
private void setupNews() {
        if(newsArticles.size() != 50) {
            NewsApiClient newsApiClient = new NewsApiClient(getString(R.string.feednews_api_key));

            newsApiClient.getEverything(
                    new EverythingRequest.Builder()
                            .q("Fitness")
                            .pageSize(50)
                            .language("en")
                            .build(),
                    new NewsApiClient.ArticlesResponseCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(ArticleResponse articleResponse) {

                            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                                newsArticles.add(new NewsArticle(articleResponse.getArticles().get(i).getTitle(),
                                        articleResponse.getArticles().get(i).getDescription(),
                                        articleResponse.getArticles().get(i).getPublishedAt(),
                                        articleResponse.getArticles().get(i).getSource().getName(),
                                        articleResponse.getArticles().get(i).getUrlToImage(),
                                        articleResponse.getArticles().get(i).getUrl()));
                            }

                            RecyclerView newsRecycler = findViewById(R.id.news_articles_list);
                            Log.d(TAG, "setup: " + newsArticles.size());
                            ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(newsRecycler, false);

                            newsRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                            RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new NewsAdapter(newsArticles, getApplicationContext());
                            newsRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                            newsRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
                            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + throwable);
                            System.out.println(throwable.getMessage());
                            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            mCheckNewsRecieved.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }

                    }
            );
```

I checked with 2 diferrent keys so probably no key problem. I checked everything in Recycleview adapter and viewholder. I read all posts for `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout` error i got in logcat so i m almost convinced that i m not getting data from newsapi.org.  So my questions as i run out of ideas is how can i debug such a problem?

UPDATE: I post recycleview adapter just in case

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final ArrayList<NewsArticle> mNewsArticle;
    private final Context mContext;

    public NewsAdapter(ArrayList<NewsArticle> mNewsArticle, Context mContext) {
        this.mNewsArticle = mNewsArticle;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public NewsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news_articles, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NewsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.articleDesc.setText(mNewsArticle.get(position).getArticleDesc());
        holder.articleName.setText(mNewsArticle.get(position).getArticleName());
        holder.articleURL.setText(mNewsArticle.get(position).getArticleURLName());
        holder.articleDate.setText(dateConfiguration(mNewsArticle.get(position).getArticleDate()));

        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: " + mNewsArticle.get(position).getArticleURLName());

        Picasso
                .with(mContext)
                .load(mNewsArticle.get(position).getArticleImageURL())
                .resize(380, 200)
                .into(holder.articleImage);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> IntentUtils.invokeToURL(mContext, mNewsArticle.get(position).getArticleURLLink()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNewsArticle.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView articleName;
        private TextView articleDesc;
        private TextView articleURL;
        private ImageView articleImage;
        private TextView articleDate;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            articleName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.article_title);
            articleDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.article_desc);
            articleImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.article_image);
            articleURL = itemView.findViewById(R.id.article_url);
            articleDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.article_date);
        }
    }

    public String dateConfiguration(String Date) {

        return Date.replace("T", " ").replace("Z", "");
    }
```

UPDATE: After checking newsapi.org it has my requests. The strange thing is that in emulator worked onced but now even if i wipe data, invalidate cache etc, the articles still loading (the old ones). In physical device i got the `mCheckNewsRecieved.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` message like it failed.

Comment: Use the android studio's debugger, put a breakpoint inside onSuccess and in onFailure. Check the local scope for the data that you are looking for and if the data is there, step through each line of the code and make sure it is getting parsed correctly. Also worth checking out whether your adapter and your viewholder is setup correctly.

Comment: @Steven Can you be a little more specific as i m familiar with logcat but not with breakpoint and other checks.